# Running SSH Workspace through c9.io on Arch Linux cannot spawn new Terminal windows without sudo reboot

Tags: cloud9-ide

Problem:  can't spawn new terminal windows in the c9.io workspace when using an SSH workspace and Arch Linux as the host OS.

Steps:

1. Arch Linux as Host OS on a Virtual Box VM setup with Vagrant on my own server
2. SSH c9 workspace
3. Clicking + symbol to spawn a new Terminal in the c9.io workspace launches a new Terminal tab but it never loads anything (blank other than a title)
4. I can spawn as many new terminal tabs as I want and nothing happens inside the c9 workspace
5. Running "top" from a SSH terminal connected to my machine, I can see that my cloud9 user has an instance of bash running underneath vfs-worker.  Tmux is running as a child of the aforementioned bash process.
6. If I type "sudo reboot" of the machine, when it comes online and c9 reconnects, all previous non-working Terminal windows will now all be functioning perfectly as would be expected in a non-SSH workspace.

I do not have issues with Ubuntu as the host OS, but with Arch Linux as the host OS I have this issue.

Comment: I am having this issue on Ubuntu. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there were errors while installing cloud9 dependencies.
If it's not the case, you should contact cloud9 support using `help>support>send support request` menu item, and someone will help to fix the issue.